# MVC prefetching data

Tags: java, android, model-view-controller

I'm working on an android project using MVC "Model -View -Controller " Design ,The problem is when I need to fetch data from the model class to the view class to be viewed I have to wait some time until data is ready, therefore the application will be frozen until data gets ready for use . How can I call data to be ready while my return method is still waiting for it and can I  be notified that the data I'm calling is ready ? Any help will be really appreciated . Thank you.

Comment: Please show your code. Try prefetching data in the memory while loading

Comment: I've searched around and found to use observer pattern .